# Where is the Lihzard Temple?

Tags: terraria-mobile

[image]

Not only have I checked the underground, but also the whole world. I also have 54 keys to the temple. Yet I can't find it. Any idea?

Comment: The temple always spawns in the underground jungle. It isn't extremely large, and I see a few black areas in what looks like the jungle. Are you sure you have fully explored the jungle?

Comment: Dont you see the image i have fully explored the undergroud jungle no sign of it

Comment: If the world was created before the 1.2 release, then the Lizhard Temple is not generated.

Comment: No i downloaded the game version 1.2.something

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gameiki.com/wiki/Lihzahrd_Temple):

> Note that although one should be generated per world, they often are generated improperly or not at all.

So, there is a chance that your world doesn't contain a temple. To fix this issue, you will unfortunately have to create a new world and look for the temple there.

Comment: I did answer the question.  There is a chance the temple doesn't exist

Comment: Ok thx guys now you mean i have to make a new world?

Comment: Sadly, yes (if you want to go to the temple and beyond).

Comment: Can i keep  up progressing in the game or is it impossible i have to restart from 0 if i want to reach the end

Comment: I don't know about mobile, but on PC you have to make a new world.  You SHOULD™ be able to keep your items and levels on your character.

Comment: Sadly you will have to kill the Wall of flesh, the three Mechanical Bosses, and Plantera again. As others have said you can use your character, weapons and supplies from this world.

Comment: @Darokrithia On all platforms, you can create a new world and still use the same character